# What caused the iOS DCIM folder structure to change?

Tags: ios, photos, filesystem

For years, whenever I connected an iOS device to my Windows computer, in file explorer I saw a `DCIM` folder with subfolders following a pattern of `100APPLE`, `101APPLE`, `102APPLE`, etc.  Today when connecting one of my devices (running iOS 14.6), I noticed those folders are gone.  Instead, the pattern seems to be `YYYY__MM` (e.g. `2013__01` and `2021__07`).  However, on a second iOS device (running iOS 14.7), the folder pattern is unchanged--I still see the original folder names.

What triggers this change?  Is there a way to switch back?  At first I thought it was updating to iOS 14.6; since my second device has an even more recent version, though, I'm wondering if there's some other necessary condition to trigger the folder name change.

I've found a [couple](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ios-14-6-dcim-folder-changes.2300057/) [references](https://twitter.com/3939tokai/status/1397470444505100292) to this around the internet, but nothing definitive.

Comment: I'd take a wild guess that no-one on Mac would ever have found this issue, as the Mac has a dedicated 'system-friendly' way of accessing the photos, but Windows doesn't. The phone never mounts on a Mac like it does on Windows, as a separate 'drive' - so no-one ever looks inside. I don't have a device still on 14.6 to test.

Comment: I noticed today on iOS 15.4.1 that the folders now follow the pattern `YYYYMM__` (e.g. `201407__` and `202206__`).

Answer (score 2):

After I upgraded my first device to iOS 14.7, the subfolder pattern switched back to `100APPLE`, `101APPLE`, `102APPLE`, etc.  This makes me think the date-based folder structure was something specifically done (or perhaps accidentally exposed to users) in iOS 14.6.